Efficiently combining list elements by matching information
I'm working with lists that have a structure something like this
l={{1,f},{2,a,y,g},{67,d,y,y},{8,t,a,q,g,w,q},{-11,a,y,g},{98,h,e}}
The first term in each sublist is always a number, and the other elements are some undetermined thing. However given that elements 2 and 5 match, I'd like to combine them to make l={{1,f,g,h},{-9,a,y,g},{67,d,y,y},{8,t,a,q}} is there an efficient approach to this problem?

One possibility. First use GatherBy to collect into groups those sublists which has same Rest.
Then go over the above result using Map, and if you find a group of length>1 then this means this group has same rest, and so add all the first elements of all list(s) in this one group, and join the rest to it.
lis = {{1, f}, {2, a, y, g}, {67, d, y, y}, {8, t, a, q, g, w, 
   q}, {-11, a, y, g}, {98, h, e}, {3, a, b}, {9, a, b}, {11, a, b}}


Now process
lis2 = Values@GroupBy[lis, Rest[#] &]
If[Length[#] == 1, Flatten@#, 
    Flatten@{Total@Map[Function[a, First[a]], #], Rest[First[#]]}] & /@ lis2



Clear["Global`*"]

lis = {{1, f}, {2, a, y, g}, {67, d, y, y}, {8, t, a, q, g, w, q}
     , {-11, a, y, g}, {98, h, e}, {3, a, b}, {9, a, b}, {11, a, b}};

KeyValueMap[Join[{#2}, #] &, GroupBy[#, Rest -> First, Total]] &@lis


{{1,f}, {-9,a,y,g}, {67,d,y,y}, {8,t,a,q,g,w,q}, {98,h,e}, {23,a,b}}


+1.  Join[{#2}, #]& could be written as Prepend.

Another possibility: ReplaceRepeated (//.)
lis={{1,f},{2,a,y,g},{67,d,y,y},{8,t,a,q,g,w,q},{-11,a,y,g},{98,h,e},{3,a,b},{9,a,b},{11,a,b}};

lis//.{a___,{m_Integer,x__},b___,{n_Integer,x__},c___}:>{a,{m+n,x},b,c}

(* {{1,f},{-9,a,y,g},{67,d,y,y},{8,t,a,q,g,w,q},{98,h,e},{23,a,b}} *)

